# Prevent TablewViewHeader to show when [tableView reloadData] is performed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar, reloaddata

does anyone know if there is a way to prevent my table view header to show (in this case a **UISearchBar**) when a `[tableView reloadData]` is performed.

I want to avoid this behaviour. The only way to show the search bar is when the user scrolls down the table.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After `[tableView reloadData];`

Setting content offset(y position) of tableView might help.

```
CGFloat nSearchBarHeight = 40;
CGPoint point = (CGPoint){0,nSearchBarHeight};
tableView.contentOffset = point;
```

Hope that helps.